# Is it possible to forward emails to an external application?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, exchange-2013

I have a scenario where I want to create an application to process all incoming mail for a particular mailbox.

I feel the simplest approach would be to try and get Exchange server to 'forward' all emails to my application.

Is it possible to configure a rule on a mailbox that forwards all emails to an application? (as opposed to just forwarding to another email address)

I would be open to any of the following application types:

- HTTP Post to a web URL
- Windows Service
- Console Application

Comment: Forward an email how? Via SMTP? Because thats the only "forward" option the MS Exchange server knows. And then your solution must be as well an SMTP server and the routing between both need to be in place. So the best option would be if your application connect to the Exchange server via webservices, IMAP, ... whatever and fetch the emails from there.

Comment: OK, I guess the answer is no then.